# Animate outgoing and incomming item in scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

I am trying to create 2d scrollview which can scroll in any direction and i have found the library for that.

But now i want to animate the items which are inside that view, like when any item is going outside then start shrinking (when going outside from any direction) and when coming inside the screen then animate to original size.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far regarding the animations?

Comment: @Benjamin nothing yet